# Suspend-resume issue - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, suspend

I've been using ubuntu for a while and I've never encountered a problem. However, yesterday after suspending the laptop, when I try to resume screen goes for blank(Neither mouse nor keyboard action works).

I've tried several solutions posted here but none of them worked like editing grub file for AMD/Nvidia drivers. The one thing I've noticed that when executing `cat /sys/power/state` command it shows `freeze mem disk`. Maybe something related with memory that causes freeze on suspend, but honestly don't have idea for a exact reason

System Details:

OS: Ubuntu LTS 20.04, Kernel 5.8.0-40-generic
CPU: AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics
GPU: Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
RAM: 8GB

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a [new kernel bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1925843) that might be at fault. Try booting with an older kernel to see if you still have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

On a freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 with the same problem, i.e. blank screen after resuming from suspend; on a different Asus GL502 laptop with GPU GeForce GTX  1060, I installed the Nvidia drivers with

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

(which replaced the Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau).   Now it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is... driver for Graphics GPU: Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics], not yet available... you may try this work around:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line as shown below:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset resume=UUID=fe4994e1-975c-47eb-97d9-e779340a84be"
```

- nomodeset is important, as long as mullins driver not yet available
- `UUID=fe4994e1-975c-47eb-97d9-e779340a84be` is your swap partition, must add also at `/etc/fstab`

After doing so, update your `grub`:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Continue with editing `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`:

```
sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

Edit the `RESUME=UUID` line:

```
RESUME=UUID=fe4994e1-975c-47eb-97d9-e779340a84be
```

- `UUID=fe4994e1-975c-47eb-97d9-e779340a84be` is your swap partition, must add also at `/etc/fstab`

Update your `initramfs`:

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
```

You may also want to doing hibernate without asking password. it still require `sudo`, but you may skip entering `sudo` password (only for hibernate).

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers
```

Add:

```
User_That_You_Allowed_To_Do_Hibernate ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate
```

- login to created user

`sudo systemctl hibernate`

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>clt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> (this should turn your whole screen into a terminal) and the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> (to come out of it.)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371512/unresponsive-black-screen-after-suspend) fits a similar description and fixed the problem for me, I followed the instructions in the accepted answer. The only change is that the file in

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf
```

already existed for me, so I added the lines described in the links inside instead of making a  new file.
I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04.4 and kernel 5.13.19

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with suspend on a macbook here's a solution that worked for me: https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=149965

More precisely:

```
1. open terminal: sudo nano /etc/default/grub
2. go to: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" " and add to: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="init_on_alloc=0"
3. save and exit
4. sudo update-grub
5. reboot pc
```