# unresponsive black screen after suspend

Tags: 20.04, graphics, login, display, bios

I have acer swift sf314-43 that running on ryzen 5500U with integrated gpu

My Ubuntu 20.04 shows black screen **after login from suspend**.

 The screen show login form but as soon as I press enter it shows black screen with no feedback.

I tried to get into TTY mode with <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + fn + (F1 / F5)</kbd> but shows nothing.

here's my `sudo dmesg -l err, warn` log :

```bsh
[    0.311135] Expanded resource Reserved due to conflict with PCI Bus 0000:00
[    0.408887] pci 0000:00:00.2: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[    0.408888] pci 0000:00:00.2: PCI INT A: not connected
[    0.468665] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
[    0.470012] platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
[    0.470014] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
[    0.470014] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
[    0.470015] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
[    0.470016] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
[    0.470016] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
[    0.470017] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
[    0.470018] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
[    0.470018] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
[    0.540591] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
[    0.541394] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
[    1.006956] acpi PNP0C14:01: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
[    1.016972] nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.
[    2.601162] systemd-journald[334]: File /var/log/journal/802b49e67af045c3aa7fdec326723765/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[    3.080393] mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
[    3.109062] acp_pdm_mach acp_pdm_mach.0: snd_soc_register_card(acp) failed: -517
[    3.139746] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for amdgpu/renoir_ta.bin failed with error -2
[    3.139751] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: PSP runtime database doesn't exist
[    3.444933] mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: Firmware init done
[    4.102258] [drm] DP Alt mode state on HPD: 0
[    4.301876] [drm] Alt mode has timed out after 199 ms
[    4.355803] amdgpu: SRAT table not found
[   17.189553] acpi AMDI0010:03: Already enumerated
```

also my `lspci -k` result:

```bsh
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] FCH SMBus Controller
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] FCH LPC Bridge
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device 3802
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
    Kernel modules: mt7921e
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 500d (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 500d
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 164c (rev c2)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1537
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1537
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
    Kernel driver in use: ccp
    Kernel modules: ccp
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Renoir USB 3.1
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Renoir USB 3.1
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    Kernel driver in use: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
04:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
04:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
```

**Edit** : I have added renoir_ta.bin but the issue still occuring. I think the problem here is SRAT table not found, is there any way I can solve this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1901687#p1901687) might help you.
It is for archlinux, but you could adapt it to ubuntu.

The suitable `.conf` file seems to be `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf` instead of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf`.

And to enable KMS, you should use `initramfs` instead of `mkinitcpio`.

1. Add `amdgpu` at the end of `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`.
2. Execute `sudo update-initramfs -u`.
3. Reboot.

**Related**

1. [Black screen after suspend on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345230/black-screen-after-suspend-on-ubuntu-21-04)
2. https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=111244
3. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204241
4. https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/f7oti1/issue_with_resume_from_suspend_black_backlit/
5. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AMDGPU#Set_module_parameters_in_kernel_command_line

Comment: I tried following one of your related issue's answer. This [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345230/black-screen-after-suspend-on-ubuntu-21-04) and it's work, Thank you!

Comment: Sorry it's taking so long to reply, since there's a lot a work i gotta do