# can not open grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, shortcut-keys, suspend

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 on ryzen 5500U & integrated GPU.

I can't open grub menu even though I already pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd> / <kbd>Esc</kbd> button when boot up. I want to downgrade My kernel version since I can't login after suspend, it shows unresponsive [black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371512/unresponsive-black-screen-after-suspend).

Kernel version :
`5.14.10-051410-generic`

`/etc/default/grub` file :

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=-1
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Try changing grub timeout line to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=5`

Comment: It is sometimes hard, but try hitting and releasing escape every half second while booting.

Comment: will do, alright

Comment: @vanadium hey, it's working

Comment: I will post this then as an answer - I also learned this the hard way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be hard to display the grub menu, but **try hitting and releasing escape every half second while booting**.

At the expense of a longer boot time, you edit the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value in `/etc/default/grub` to add some seconds of waiting time. Then, Grub will wait some time before booting the default entry. During that time, you can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd>, or hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to display the menu.

Here is how you can [edit the grub configuration](https://askubuntu.com/a/1154020/558158).